How to use Java's ImageIO to write JPEG with large embedded thumbnail?
I'm using javax.imageio.ImageIO to write JPEGs. By default: if I try to write an image with a thumbnail that thumbnail is clipped to 255x255.
Is it possible using only ImageIO classes to embed a thumbnail that is 300x300px?
I (think I) understand that this is because ImageIO's implementation uses an old-fashioned APP0 marker (using JFIF, instead of the more modern EXIF), and the width and height MUST be expressed as bytes.
However:
I'm looking through Sun's code, and I think (?) it should be possible to embed larger thumbnails if I can trigger the code that will use the JFIFThumbJPEG implementation. The default thumbnail is written as a raw table of RGB bytes, but the JFIFThumbJPEG will (I think) embed a separate mini JPEG in the file. Which should be capable of having a width & height that are not constrained to 1 byte.
Here is a unit test that demonstrates the failure:
import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;


/**
 * This demonstrates that ImageIO fails to write a JPEG thumbnail that is larger than 255x255.
 * <p>
 * However, when I did through the implementation/specification, it looks like ImageIO *is*
 * capable of supporting different types of thumbnails. I think if I can figure out
 * how to write IIOMetaData to use a JFIFThumbJPEG then I may (?) be able to write thumbnails
 * of arbitrary size.
 * </p>
 */
public class TestThumbnails extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void testImageIOThumbnailSizes() throws IOException {
        BufferedImage largeImage = new BufferedImage(1000, 1000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        // a value smaller than 255 will work:
        BufferedImage goodThumbnail = new BufferedImage(200, 200, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        // a value larger than 255 will be cropped to 255
        BufferedImage badThumbnail = new BufferedImage(300, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        testThumbnail(largeImage, goodThumbnail);
        System.out.println("first thumbnail passed");

        testThumbnail(largeImage, badThumbnail);
        System.out.println("second thumbnail passed");
    }

    private void testThumbnail(BufferedImage largeImage, BufferedImage thumbnail) throws IOException {
        Iterator<ImageWriter> iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpg");
        ImageWriter w = iter.next();

        byte[] jpegData;
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            IIOImage iioImage = new IIOImage(largeImage, Arrays.asList(thumbnail), null);

            ImageOutputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(byteOut);
            w.setOutput(stream);
            w.write(iioImage);
            jpegData = byteOut.toByteArray();
        }

        testReadingThumbnail(jpegData, thumbnail.getWidth(), thumbnail.getHeight());
    }

    private void testReadingThumbnail(byte[] jpegData, int expectedThumbnailWidth, int expectedThumbnailHeight) throws IOException {
        Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReadersBySuffix("jpg");
        ImageReader reader = iter.next();

        try (ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(jpegData)) {
            reader.setInput(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(byteIn));

            // Thumbnails larger than 255x255 are trimmed. I want to read back
            // a thumbnail that uses the dimensions I passed in:

            assertEquals(expectedThumbnailWidth, reader.getThumbnailWidth(0, 0));
            assertEquals(expectedThumbnailHeight, reader.getThumbnailHeight(0, 0));
        }
    }
}


I suggest that you try TwelveMonkeys library. Latest release is here. It enhances class ImageIO.

Thanks. I'm not opposed to TwelveMonkeys, but in this case I was looking for something that worked with a standard JRE install and no additional libraries.

TwelveMonkeys does not have special support for writing large JPEG thumbnails at the moment. But I think your solution below is very interesting.

I figured it out. The writeJPEG method below is capable of writing JPEG thumbnails larger than 255x255.
Limitations include:

The JPEG compression is stuck at 75%. (As of this writing I can't see a way to modify that.)
The thumbnail is embedded as its own inner JPEG. And that JPEG must be under ~65KB, or the JPEGImageWriter fails with an exception. In this test case that meant I could make a thumbnail up to 1500x1500px, but the max dimensions will vary depending on how the image compresses. I should definitely be able to write a 300x300 or 400x400 thumbnail, though.

import junit.framework.TestCase;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadata;
import javax.imageio.metadata.IIOMetadataNode;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class TestThumbnails extends TestCase {

    /**
     * Write an image to an output stream.
     * <p>
     * Normally ImageIO writes JPEG thumbnails using a JFIF APP0 marker segment, which guarantees
     * a lossless thumbnail but it constrains the thumbnail to 255x255. This method will switch to
     * a JFIF *extension* APP0 marker segment for larger thumbnails. This lets us embed a thumbnail
     * of arbitrary size as another JPEG. This offers better compression, but it uses the default
     * JPEG compression level (see com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEG.DEFAULT_QUALITY).
     * </p>
     * <p>
     * This will throw an exception if the thumbnail ends up being
     * over 65KB (after compression at 75% quality).
     * </p>
     *
     * @param out the stream to write the JPEG image to.
     * @param bufferedImage the large image to write.
     * @param thumbnail the thumbnail to encode with the image.
     * @param jpegQuality the JPEG quality from 0-1. Where 1 is lossless.
     */
    public static void writeJPEG(OutputStream out, BufferedImage bufferedImage, BufferedImage thumbnail, float jpegQuality) throws IOException {
        Iterator<ImageWriter> iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersBySuffix("jpg");
        ImageWriter jpegWriter = iter.next();

        IIOImage iioImage = new IIOImage(bufferedImage, Arrays.asList(thumbnail), null);

        ImageWriteParam param = jpegWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();
        param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
        param.setCompressionQuality(jpegQuality);

        if (thumbnail.getWidth() > 255 || thumbnail.getHeight() > 255) {
            // this complex / cryptic code lets us activate the JFIFthumbJPEG logic that lets us
            // embed larger thumbnails:
            ImageTypeSpecifier imageType = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            IIOMetadata metadata = jpegWriter.getDefaultImageMetadata(imageType, param);

            // String formatName = com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JPEG.nativeStreamMetadataFormatName
            String formatName = "javax_imageio_jpeg_image_1.0";

            IIOMetadataNode rootNode = new IIOMetadataNode(formatName);
            IIOMetadataNode JPEGvariety = new IIOMetadataNode();
            IIOMetadataNode markerSequenceNode = new IIOMetadataNode();
            rootNode.appendChild(JPEGvariety);
            rootNode.appendChild(markerSequenceNode);

            IIOMetadataNode jfifMarkerSegment = new IIOMetadataNode();
            JPEGvariety.appendChild(jfifMarkerSegment);

            IIOMetadataNode jfxx = new IIOMetadataNode("JFXX");
            jfifMarkerSegment.appendChild(jfxx);

            IIOMetadataNode app0JFXX = new IIOMetadataNode();
            // see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#JFIF_extension_APP0_marker_segment
            app0JFXX.setAttribute("extensionCode", "16");
            jfxx.appendChild(app0JFXX);

            IIOMetadataNode JFIFthumbJPEG = new IIOMetadataNode("JFIFthumbJPEG");
            app0JFXX.appendChild(JFIFthumbJPEG);

            metadata.setFromTree(formatName, rootNode);
            iioImage.setMetadata(metadata);
        }

        ImageOutputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(out);
        jpegWriter.setOutput(stream);
        jpegWriter.write(iioImage);
    }

    @Test
    public void testImageIOThumbnailSizes() throws IOException {
        BufferedImage largeImage = createImage(1000);

        // a value smaller than 255 works without any special intervention:
        BufferedImage simpleThumbnail = createImage(200);

        // the smaller thumbnail should be encoded losslessly, so we can use an RGB delta of 0
        testThumbnail(largeImage, simpleThumbnail, 0);
        System.out.println("PASSED: thumbnail size " + simpleThumbnail.getWidth() + "x" + simpleThumbnail.getHeight());
        
        for (int size = 300; size <= 1500; size += 100) {
            BufferedImage biggerThumbnail = createImage(size);

            // the larger thumbnail will have compression artifacts, so allow some RGB delta
            testThumbnail(largeImage, biggerThumbnail, 10);
            System.out.println("PASSED: thumbnail size " + biggerThumbnail.getWidth() + "x" + biggerThumbnail.getHeight());
        }
        
        // at size = 1600 we get a IllegalThumbException because the encoded thumbnail exceeds ~65536 KB. That limit
        // is based on the allocation of bytes, so it's impossible to predict exactly what *dimension* will trigger
        // that condition. (Since the byte size of a JPEG will vary depending on how well the image data compresses.)
    }

    /**
     * This creates a HSB gradient image. This will be easy to scan later in
     * {@link #assertSimilar(BufferedImage, BufferedImage, int)}, and because it's a gradient it
     * should compress well without clunky compression artifacts.
     */
    private BufferedImage createImage(int size) {
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        for (int y = 0; y < bi.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < bi.getWidth(); x++) {
                int rgb = Color.HSBtoRGB( (float)x / ((float) size), 1, (float)y / ((float) size) );
                bi.setRGB(x, y, rgb);
            }
        }
        return bi;
    }

    private void testThumbnail(BufferedImage largeImage, BufferedImage thumbnail, int allowedRGBDelta) throws IOException {
        byte[] jpegData;
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            writeJPEG(byteOut, largeImage, thumbnail, .8f);
            jpegData = byteOut.toByteArray();
        }

        testReadingThumbnail(jpegData, thumbnail, allowedRGBDelta);
    }

    /**
     * This reads back a JPEG and asserts that the embedded thumbnail matches what we expect.
     */
    private void testReadingThumbnail(byte[] jpegData, BufferedImage expectedThumbnail, int allowedRGBDelta) throws IOException {
        Iterator<ImageReader> iter = ImageIO.getImageReadersBySuffix("jpg");
        ImageReader reader = iter.next();

        try (ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(jpegData)) {
            reader.setInput(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(byteIn));

            assertEquals(expectedThumbnail.getWidth(), reader.getThumbnailWidth(0, 0));
            assertEquals(expectedThumbnail.getHeight(), reader.getThumbnailHeight(0, 0));

            BufferedImage actualThumbnail = reader.readThumbnail(0, 0);

            assertSimilar(expectedThumbnail, actualThumbnail, allowedRGBDelta);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make sure two images are nearly the same. This examines the RGB of each pixel and
     * asserts that each channel of both images is at least `allowedRGBDelta` units similar.
     */
    private void assertSimilar(BufferedImage expectedImg, BufferedImage actualImg, int allowedRGBDelta) {
        assertEquals(expectedImg.getWidth(), actualImg.getWidth());
        assertEquals(expectedImg.getHeight(), actualImg.getHeight());
        for (int y = 0; y <expectedImg.getHeight(); y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < expectedImg.getWidth(); x++) {
                int argb1 = expectedImg.getRGB(x,y);
                int argb2 = actualImg.getRGB(x,y);

                int r1 = (argb1 >> 16) & 0xff;
                int g1 = (argb1 >> 8) & 0xff;
                int b1 = (argb1 >> 0) & 0xff;

                int r2 = (argb2 >> 16) & 0xff;
                int g2 = (argb2 >> 8) & 0xff;
                int b2 = (argb2 >> 0) & 0xff;

                assertTrue("(" + x + "," + y+") r1 = " + r1 + ", r2 = " + r2, Math.abs(r1 - r2) <= allowedRGBDelta);
                assertTrue("(" + x + "," + y+") g1 = " + g1 + ", g2 = " + g2, Math.abs(g1 - g2) <= allowedRGBDelta);
                assertTrue("(" + x + "," + y+") b1 = " + b1 + ", b2 = " + b2, Math.abs(b1 - b2) <= allowedRGBDelta);
            }
        }
    }
}


For reference the non-public Sun code that this is activating is in com.sun.imageio.plugins.jpeg.JFIFMarkerSegment. Search for this phrase to read more: JFIFThumbJPEG(BufferedImage thumb)
